# How to reference a namespace from a specific assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

So here is my problem.

- My (test) project references both Castle Windsor and Rhino Mocks.
- I am creating a class which implements Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor from the Castle.Core.dll assembly
- In building Rhino Mocks, Ayende used Castle.Core.Interceptor and includes the whole darn namespace inside the Rhino.Mocks.dll

So when I try to build, I get the error

> The type
>   'Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor'
>   exists in both
>   'c:...\Libraries\Rhino.Mocks.dll' and
>   'c:...\Libraries\Castle.Core.dll'

How then do I specify that I want to use the IInterceptor instance from the Castle.Core.dll rather than the one included in Rhino Mocks?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Let's throw the specific answer up here in case someone comes along later.
From article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx).

- Select one of the two assemblies under project references (in my case I selected Castle.Core).  Hit F4 to bring up properties and enter alias CastleCore
- At the top of the problematic cs file put `extern alias CastleCore;`
- Reference your class with `CastleCore::Castle.Core.Interceptors.IInterceptor`.  Or in my case I simply did:

using cci = CastleCore::Castle.Core.Interceptors;

and can now reference

```
cci.IInterceptor
```

Comment: In my case I am not able to enter an alias name in the properties section when hitting F4, so I found a solution of adding the alias name in the .csproj https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201437/dapper-ambiguous-extension-methods/55620553#55620553

Answer (score 7):

You can use an [`extern alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) to alias one of the assemblies to prevent the ambiguity.