# Change the identity of a dll

Tags: c#, dll

I'd like to change the identity of a dll, that is, if you look at the identity property in Visual studio, I'd like it to have a different name there. The reason I need to do this is because I have two dlls of different versions, and need to use them in the same application. I have looked into setting the alias property to something different (following [this guide](http://www.lloydkinsella.net/blog/2012/07/13/extern-alias-underused-or-unknown/)), but it did not work right, so I'd like to change the dll, so the application sees it as something different. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this question helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517058/how-to-reference-a-namespace-from-a-specific-assembly/517169#517169

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I'm not looking to use aliases.

Comment: Why not alias ? Any special reason .. wt if it's the only way ;)

Comment: I get this annoying error, and cannot figure it out no matter how much I google it: The extern alias '*******' was not specified in a /reference option