# Dapper ambiguous extension methods

Tags: c#, dapper

I am testing Dapper as a ORM solution and ran into a problem with some extension methods like `Execute` or `QueryMultiple`:

```
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    con.Open();
    string sql = @"
        select * from Customer where Id = @id;
        select * from Address where CustomerId = @id;";

    // QueryMultiple extension ambiguous?
    using (var multi = con.QueryMultiple(sql, new { id = 1 }))
    {
        Customer customer = multi.Read<Customer>().Single();
        Address address = multi.Read<Address>().Single();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

I get the error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryMultiple(System.Data.IDbConnection, string, object, System.Data.IDbTransaction, int?, System.Data.CommandType?)' and 'Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryMultiple(System.Data.IDbConnection, string, dynamic, System.Data.IDbTransaction, int?, System.Data.CommandType?)'

and don't know how to properly solve this. The Dapper examples didn't mention such a problem and simply used `QueryMultiple`. I was able to circumvent the ambiguity using

```
var multi = con.QueryMultiple(new CommandDefinition(sql, new { id = 1 }))
```

But is that really necessary? Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't get that compiler error. But i have only one `QueryMultiple`-overload with these parameters: `IDbConnection cnn, string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Looks like it's potentially an issue with referencing multiple DLLs? It shouldn't be possible for dapper to specify an overload with `dynamic` .. at least as far as I've tried, I get a compile error trying to create such an overload.

Comment: Maybe. Do you have another `SqlMapper`-file somewhere in the solution? Search for `QueryMultiple` project wide. Maybe an old version.

Comment: There's definitely no more `dynamic` overload in dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/b87d958314b1a85f52c7ef37b78d3740154b4d04

Comment: Setup the same project again, this time without DapperExtensions and now it seems to work fine.

Comment: This conversation here just brought me to my working solution after hours of working to solve the problem, I added a post here, I hope it can be helpful for some.

Comment: odd!! does this work? var multi = con.QueryMultiple(sql, (object)new { id = 1 })

Answer (score 8):

I bumped into the same problem after I added the package `MiniProfiler.Providers.SqlServer`, which depends on the `Dapper.StrongName` package, which depends on `Dapper`.

[image]

Obviously I didn't want to use the already referenced package of MiniProfiler, since it is always better to have control, like updating it when a new version is released.

The solution to resolving ambiguous code between assemblies is to assign an [`extern alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) name/s to at least one of the assembly packages, so when you then want to refer to one of them, you can then specify which one you want to reference by using the `alias name`.

> Here is the solution that worked for me:

To give an `alias name` to assembly `Dapper.StrongName`, I added the following to my `.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="StrongNameAlias" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'Dapper.StrongName'">
      <Aliases>MP_DapperStrongNameAlias</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
 </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

And then, if you'd want to refer to that, you can reference the assembly `namespace` by its newly added `alies` in `.cs` file, with the [`:: operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifer):

```
using MP_DapperStrongNameAlias::Dapper;
```

So now you can freely add `using Dapper;`, and it won't conflict anymore.

This Article might be helpful: [C# 2.0: Using different versions of the same dll in one application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/11/30/c-2-0-using-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-one-application/)