# C# Linq Ambiguous call Between System.Linq and System.Collections

Tags: c#, linq, collections

There are similar questions to this - but so far none of them helped.

I'm calling:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```

Then in a section of my code, VS is pointing out errors in the LINQ methods (.Last() and .Max() ). I hovered over the .Max(). The error says:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>)'

I've tried re-installing all of my references and packages, I restarted VS, IIS (this is a website).
VS recognizes System.Linq so that's not an issue....

I can't figure out why this is all the sudden throwing errors.

[image]

Comment: It seems you somehow have two distinct `System.Linq.Enumerable` candidates.

Comment: How is this possible? I thought VS prevents you from adding identical references

Comment: It doesn't have to be identical references. Someone being oversmart and implementing a `System.Linq.Enumerable` is enough.

Comment: How should I go about finding this additional reference?

Comment: You can try to [reference the System.Linq namespace from a specific assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517058/how-to-reference-a-namespace-from-a-specific-assembly) to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Comment out `using System.Collections.Generic;`. Then `Go to definition` / `Go to implementation` on the `Max` call - where does it take you?

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if anywhere in your code or in a referenced assemby someone has had the horrible horrible idea of implementing their own `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods and not knowing better, used the same namespace as the ones provided by the framework:

- Alpha assembly rolls their own `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods in `System.Linq` namespace:

  ```
  namespace System.Linq {
      public static class MyEnumerable {
          public static T Max<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) { //...
          }
      //... 
      }
  }
  ```
- Assembly Charlie thinks Alpha is great due to some other functionality it provides and references it completely oblivious to the nasty surprise it hides inside.

  ```
  using System.Linq; //woops

  namespace Charlie {
      class C {
          void Foo() {
              var l = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3 };
              var m = l.Max() /*compile time error. Ambiguous call*/ } }
  }
  ```

I don't know if this can be your case but its a probable scenario. Another potential candidate could be some versioning conflict but I'm not really sure if that is even possible in VS. I've never run into anything similar with `System.*` namespaces.

Comment: ahhh  f***.... I just did a find all of System.Linq and currently nothing sticks out, but I think you are on to something.